# Pre-compute len(range(start, stop,step) )

Tags: python, indexing, slice

How do I compute the number of elements that would result from a call to `range(start, stop, step)` before I actually call it.

The context is that I'm implementing slice indexing into an object

```
def __init__(self, impl_object):
   self.impl=impl_object # the object that actually holds (or generates) an array of values
def __getitem__(self, key):
    if isinstance(key, slice):
         (start,stop,step)=key.indices( self.impl.numValues() )
         # It would be nice to know how many items I'm dealing with
         # here
    ...snip...
```

I've convinced myself that for `step>0`
`len(range(start,stop,step))==(start-stop+step-1)/step`

but I don't see how to generalize this for negative steps.

Edit: I require (strongly prefer) that the solution take `O(1)` time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is

```
len(xrange(start, stop, step))
```

`xrange.__len__` calculates the number of elements it would `yield`, without constructing the range in memory.

Comment: Won't that take O(N) time? (I know that Iwasn't clear when I asked).

Comment: @Dave: no, `xrange` never constructs the range. Try `len(xrange(1000000000000000000))`.

Comment: Can you explain how that works?  It seems like  something is going on under the hood for `len(xrange)` to short-circuit like that.

Comment: @Dave: `xrange` knows the formula you're looking for :) An `xrange` object is basically a `(start, stop, step)` triple with methods that make it pretend to be a list of integers.

Comment: Evidence: `next(xrange(1,10))` throws a TypeError stating that `xrange` object is not an iterator.

Comment: The [xrange documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=xrange#xrange) notes a CPython implementation detail limiting the size of the arguments and the number of elements. So it seems this approach will also limit the slices that the object can support. May or may not be a problem, but probably should be considered.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber: correct, but if a `range` is to be constructed eventually, then the failure for very large integers would probably be a good thing.

Comment: @larsmans Probably, but we don't really know enough about the object to say how it should fail. The bigger concern, I think, would be something like `n=1000000000000000000000000000; len(xrange(n, n+2))`, which is fine as a range but fails as xrange. Not that I've ever had any reason to do that...

Answer (score 2):

If your `start`, `stop`, and `step` are consistent with [the implementation-specific limitations for `xrange`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) (for instance CPython 2.*x* requires that they be ' "short" Python integers'), you can get the number of values that `range(start, stop, step)` would contain by calling:

```
len(xrange(start, stop, step))
```

Under the hood, the `xrange()` call returns an [xrange object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-xrange):

> XRange objects have very little behavior: they only support indexing,
>   iteration, and the len() function.

The `len()` call is O(1), because the xrange type implements the `__len__` method with the calculation based on the parameters passed, and `len()` finds that the object passed to it implements `__len__`, and it calls it to get the length.

If your `start`, `stop`, and `step` might not work with `xrange()`, here's a function (to the credit of [a blog post with an xrange implementation](http://late.am/post/2012/06/18/what-the-heck-is-an-xrange) with help from [a Hacker News discussion](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4129658)):

```
def len_range(start, stop, step):
    return max(0, (stop - start) // step + bool((stop - start) % step))
```

Comment: PyPy's `get_len_of_range()` is probably a bit more battle-tested: https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/default/pypy/module/__builtin__/functional.py#cl-16

Comment: i.e. the `len_range` implementation above may have bugs that pypy's `get_len_of_range()` implementation does not have

Answer (score 0):

Try using abs(step) rather than step.